# JQuery DataTables Pagination with Caching Next Button Only Working On First Page

Tags: jquery, datatable, pagination

Good Morning Everyone,

Just want to start by saying thanks to everyone for their time and help!

I have seen a number of posts both on S.O. and at the DataTables forums (the latter, mostly in the "legacy" version of DataTables) that discuss this problem and end up marking it "solved," so I am aware of the commonly proposed solutions. In other words, this is not a duplicate, as far as I'm aware.

The problem is this: DataTables server-side pagination, with client-side page caching, has a "next" button which doesn't work. The pagination itself works fine, the caching works fine, the data coming to and from the server is fine. The "previous" button works fine, and clicking on the page numbers to navigate between the table pages works fine in terms of displaying the data.

The standard proposed solution has been to ensure that the JSON response has the correct values set in the "recordsTotal" and "recordsFiltered" parameters. However, I can confirm that in my case the two are indeed the same value, with no records filtered out.

The initial load of the table displays the correct counts and data, as you can see in the first screenshot.

The second screenshot is what the table looks like after the button "next" is clicked once. Note the label "Showing 0, 101 to 533 of 533 records." If I click the previous button at this point, it works and correctly displays the first page. If I navigate to any other page with the page buttons, the next button stops working completely, while previous continues to function.

The third screenshot illustrates what the table is "supposed" to look like, and what it actually does look like if I just click on page "2" in the navigation.

I am not even sure where to look because all of the variables that I'm in control of appear to be getting set correctly. It almost looks like something in the JQuery/DataTables code is concatenating two strings instead of adding two integers. I thought that maybe this was happening in the pipelining/caching code, but I have been unable to find the source, or maybe I just don't understand how it runs arithmetic...

The caching is set up in such a way that it will hold on to 50 records in the client, loading them 10 at a time into the table. When a call to the server happens, the "next" or "previous" 50 are fetched every time we cross a threshold.

In case it is relevant, the code I'm using for caching is a slight modification of the example code DataTables provides at https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html. Although I will note that when I disabled caching on my table, the problem did not change at all.

So... if anyone's got any idea where I should look for clues or solutions, your help would be much appreciated!

```
[![Screen1][1]][1]
[![Screen2][2]][2]
[![Screen3][3]][3]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pzup.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qykJC.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2Pu6.png
```

EDIT: Sorry about the way the screenshots aren't displayed. I couldn't submit it the way it rendered by default for some reason. The Validation kept telling me that I had "code not formatted as code" in my submission. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, even though this is terrible form (poor show, poor show), I've found an answer to my own question. Please bear in mind that I've spent hours on this prior to asking the question in the first place =)...

Anyway, what happened was a failure to convert from a "string" to a "number" type during DataTable initialization (so I was near to the answer when I said that there was concatenation happening). My code was passing in "10" as the display length of the table to the DataTables code. Apparently no conversion took place internally (that is, DataTables made no effort to convert the parameter to a number), which surprised me, but it's still my fault for making that assumption in the first place.

If there's a clearer explanation, please feel free to share =).

Thanks, everyone!